IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line [cookie:userData=%7B%22access_token] does not conform to RFC 7230. The request has been rejected
I have a springboot application for restFul webservice. The tomcat was upgraded to 8.5.99. Since then I get the error when I pass the cookie from a file in UNIX.
this is my curlcurl -i -s https://localhost:18080/myApp/login -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"authType":"LOCAL","password":"admin","username":"admin"}' --compressed --insecure >token.out
when I run cat token.out -A
I get
cat token.out -A
userData=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%227d35cdeb-50b2-4fd4-b522-9f985c72de9b%22%2C%22role%22%3A%5B1%2C10%2C16%2C22%5D%2C%22authType%22%3A%22LOCAL%22%2C%22user%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password_regex%22%3A%22%28%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5C%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B__special%5D%29.%7B8%2C%7D%29%22%2C%22special_chars%22%3A%22%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5D%5E_%60+%7B%5C%5C%7C%7D%7E%22%7D^M$

we can see ^M$ is added.
When I pass this file in the curl as below I get the error
curl -v -i -s -k --cookie "$(cat token.out)" -X GET https://localhost:18080/myapp/get/namespace/
> Cookie: userData=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%227d35cdeb-50b2-4fd4-b522-9f985c72de9b%22%2C%22role%22%3A%5B1%2C10%2C16%2C22%5D%2C%22authType%22%3A%22LOCAL%22%2C%22user%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password_regex%22%3A%22%28%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5C%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B__special%5D%29.%7B8%2C%7D%29%22%2C%22special_chars%22%3A%22%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5D%5E_%60+%7B%5C%5C%7C%7D%7E%22%7D



< HTTP/1.1 400
HTTP/1.1 400
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 3004
Content-Length: 3004
< Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2024 09:29:38 GMT
Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2024 09:29:38 GMT
< Connection: close
Connection: close

<
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p><p><b>Message</b> The HTTP header line [cookie:userData=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%227d35cdeb-50b2-4fd4-b522-9f985c72de9b%22%2C%22role%22%3A%5B1%2C10%2C16%2C22%5D%2C%22authType%22%3A%22LOCAL%22%2C%22user%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password_regex%22%3A%22%28%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5C%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B__special%5D%29.%7B8%2C%7D%29%22%2C%22special_chars%22%3A%22%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5D%5E_%60+%7B%5C%5C%7C%7D%7E%22%7DD] does not conform to RFC 7230. The request has been rejected.</p><p><b>Description</b> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HTTP header line [cookie:userData=%7B%22access_token%22%3A%227d35cdeb-50b2-4fd4-b522-9f985c72de9b%22%2C%22role%22%3A%5B1%2C10%2C16%2C22%5D%2C%22authType%22%3A%22LOCAL%22%2C%22user%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password_regex%22%3A%22%28%28%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.*%5C%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.*%5B__special%5D%29.%7B8%2C%7D%29%22%2C%22special_chars%22%3A%22%21%5C%22%23%24%25%26%27%28%29*%2B%2C-.%2F%3A%3B%3C%3D%3E%3F%40%5B%5D%5E_%60+%7B%5C%5C%7C%7D%7E%22%7DD] does not conform to RFC 7230. The request has been rejected.
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.skipLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:1080)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:980)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:606)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:514)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
</pre><p><b>Note</b> The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server     logs.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.5.99</h3></body></html>

the same API works fine in older tomcat version.
In the new version, if I pass the cookie directly by copying from login response instead of file, it works.
I tried to change my tomcat configuration in springboot but no go.
@Configuration
public class TomcatConfig {
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            context.setCookieProcessor(new LegacyCookieProcessor());
        }
    };
    return factory;
}
}

How do I resolve this. Please advise.
